# $router is missing on the vue interface

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue with typescript (no babel) from the vue/cli.

I want to use router: `this.$router` but I got error message: 
`Property '$router' does not exist on type`.

```
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

export default class App extends Vue {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.$router. // <- Property '$router' does not exist on type
  }
}
```

Also I can't see any definition of `$router` on `vue` interface!

[image]

How to solve that please?

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in the `created` (or `mounted`) function instead of the constructor